# Date use in linear regression and conversion of date to numbers using spark mllib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I want to use a date in linear regression.
So I have to convert it to a number. And I have to set lowest date 0 and continuously increase a number as per date difference.

Then I can use date field in Linear Regression using Scala, Spark MLlib.
I have dataframe ready with some fields including date.
For example,

```
| date       | id |
| 01-01-2017 | 12 |
| 01-02-2016 | 13 |
| 05-05-2016 | 22 |
```

For a string, I have implemented using one hot encoding technique. But for date how can I set first date to 0 and then increase number as per difference?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depend purely on a model you want to create. For very basic trend modeling you can just cast your data to Unix timestamp:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val parsed = df.withColumn("date", unix_timestamp($"date", "dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

No additional processing should be necessary, but you can of course shift it to start at 0, or rescale to more convenient scale.

More advance modeling would including extracting different components like `month` or `dayofweek`. These in general should be treated as categorical variables, and one-hot-encoded.

Comment: Might expressing the date as "days since 1/1/2017" or "days since "1/1/2016" or something similar be worth a try?

Comment: I don't think so. It won't change interpretation of model which will be change per unit of time.

Comment: Worked!!
Date is converted to number so directly one hot encoding can be applied.
Thanks a lot!!